# Manage doobie connections with Hikari

Tags: scala, doobie

I am connecting and firing queries on postgres in my scala play framework application. While optimizing my application, I saw that before firing **any query** a CONNECT call is being made to Postgres which AFAIK is not necessary before every SQL query and the connection pool should've been used. I tried to find the issue but was unable to figure out.

This is my code

```
object SQLClient extends SQLClientTrait {
  protected val rdsConfig = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("rds.config")

  private implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContexts.synchronous)
  private val rdsEngine: Resource[IO, HikariTransactor[IO]] = initialiseRDSEngine()

  private def initialiseRDSEngine(): Resource[IO, HikariTransactor[IO]] = {
    val transactor = for {
      ce <- ExecutionContexts.fixedThreadPool[IO](20)
      be <- Blocker[IO]
      xa <- HikariTransactor.newHikariTransactor[IO](
        "org.postgresql.Driver",
        s"jdbc:postgresql://${rdsConfig.getString("host")}:${rdsConfig.getString("port")}/${rdsConfig.getString("dbname")}?prepareThreshold=${rdsConfig.getString("prepareThreshold")}",
        rdsConfig.getString("username"),
        rdsConfig.getString("password"),
        ce,
        be
      )
    } yield xa
    transactor
  } 

  override def getData(query: String): Future[List[Data]] = {
    try {
      val response = rdsEngine.use { xa =>
        Fragment.const(query)
          .query[ConsentDbModel]
          .to[List]
          .transact(xa)
      }.unsafeToFuture()

      logger.debug(s"Successfully executed query: ${query.trim}")
      response
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception =>
        ex.printStackTrace()
        throw RDSException(ex.getMessage)
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something while initializing or making a query?

Comment: How long are your queries taking?

Comment: DML Queries are fast but CONNECT is increasing latencies of my APIs.

Comment: One thing I would recommend is to not use the synchronous `ExecutionContext`, since it will run the query on the same thread that acquires the connection. I would be curious to see if that might cause some weird interplay with the `HikariTransactor`. Instead, you might want to see if a `cachedThreadPool` works for you, as well as not passing the connection execution context directly to the transactor, but rather let it size itself based on the configured number of connections to pool. Example: https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/14-Managing-Connections.html#using-a-hikaricp-connection-pool

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is using globals - your code is defined in `object` so it has to be called as a global method. Meanwhile `Resource`s like this are intended to be run ONCE in your `main`, so that this content of `use` reuse the same connection pool.

If your `SQLClient` needed connection pool it could take it as a dependency through a constructor:

```
object Main extends IOApp {

  private val transactor = for {
      ce <- ExecutionContexts.fixedThreadPool[IO](20)
      be <- Blocker[IO]
      xa <- HikariTransactor.newHikariTransactor[IO](
        "org.postgresql.Driver",
        s"jdbc:postgresql://${rdsConfig.getString("host")}:${rdsConfig.getString("port")}/${rdsConfig.getString("dbname")}?prepareThreshold=${rdsConfig.getString("prepareThreshold")}",
        rdsConfig.getString("username"),
        rdsConfig.getString("password"),
        ce,
        be
      )
    } yield xa  

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = transactor.use { xa =>
    val client = new SQLClient(xa)
    IO {
      // use client here
      ExitCode.Success
    }
  }
}

class SQLClient(xa: HikariTransactor[IO]) extends SQLClientTrait {
  protected val rdsConfig = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("rds.config")

  private implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContexts.synchronous)

  override def getData(query: String): Future[List[Data]] = {
    try {
      val response =
        Fragment.const(query)
          .query[ConsentDbModel]
          .to[List]
          .transact(xa)
          .unsafeToFuture()

      logger.debug(s"Successfully executed query: ${query.trim}")
      response
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception =>
        ex.printStackTrace()
        throw RDSException(ex.getMessage)
    }
  }
}
```

In case you need to use Cats within some non-Cats code, I would recommend reading about [`Resource` allocated](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/2.x/cats/effect/Resource.html#allocated%5BG%5Bx%5D%3E:F%5Bx%5D,B%3E:A%5D(implicitF:cats.effect.BracketThrow%5BG%5D):G%5B(B,G%5BUnit%5D)%5D) and how to use it.

Comment: but initialiseRDSEngine method will be called only once and this Resource will be created only once, on first call to getData method as rdsEngine variable will be initialized at that time, right?

Comment: No, `IO[A]` monad is `() => A` in disguise. `Resource` is a way to cleanup something which is initialized - you store a pair constructor function  + cleanup function together. Functions, not the final values. So even though you have `Resource[IO, ...]` stored as `val rdsEngine` it's a val storing `() => HikariTransactor` (and `HikariTransactor => ()` for cleanup/closing) - you initialize it (start connection, etc) and close (disconnect) it every time you run `rdsEngine.use { ... }. unsafeToFuture()` - unsafe methods are called this way because you really should read what you're actually doing.

Comment: IIUC the documentation seems to show the pattern, which is not a problem for the example itself, but doesn't seem to be a good practice for a long running application -- should this be mentioned to the maintainers or am I misunderstanding? https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/14-Managing-Connections.html#using-a-hikaricp-connection-pool

Comment: The example you mentioned: 1. uses `IOApp` - that means you, yes, have a global `object`... which defines only a `main` method so 2. the `val` you have there IS initialized and cleaned up exactly ONCE - in said `main`. `run` is a utility using `IO` that `IOApp` calls inside the `main` to run the computation exactly once. TL;DT in this example it is OK because `val` is called directly by `main` and no one else. In OPs case he calls it himself repeatedly. These things are considered obvious if you know what Cats Effect and IO monad are supposed to do... but I guess op was not given this context.

Comment: So, there are 2 problems here: not understanding the difference between `IO` and `Future` - that explains why op assumed that value is initialized once because it is `val`. The other is not understanding what is `Resource` - the same problem would pop up if OP used, IDK, `scala.util.Using(someWayToGetTransactor) { transactor => callDBWithoutFutureWrapper }`. If you know that IO is just a blueprint - it doesn't start on its own, it doesn't caches - and that Resource would initialize and destroy each you you use it - the behavior is expected, see https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/tutorial

Comment: Also, if you see any method starting with `unsafe` and you have _no experience with Cats Effect_ - *do not call it*, because your intuitions will not align with intuitions of long time CE users. As a matter of the fact, I think someone recommended OP to use Doobe without any context - Doobie is used to construct SQL queries through `Fragments` interpolators to avoid SQL injection. The example uses `Fragment.const(query)` which throws that functionality out of the window. Since OP does not use referential transparency, nor SQL injection prevention there is hardly any reason to use Doobie.

Comment: Thanks @MateuszKubuszok for this information. One more question: I have a play framework application that makes calls to doobie for each API call. So Do I have to create the hikari transactor in a Module and inject that in SQLClient and use it.

Comment: Play Framework does not impose any way of doing dependency injection, and whether one use: cake pattern (don't), Guice, Macwire or manually calling constructors is up to them. I'd just inject it, but if you want to use Doobie, read about Cats Effect, `IO` (and how it's different to `Future`), `Resource`, etc first.

Comment: Thanks @MateuszKubuszok. I read about IO and got some clarity but I am still unable to find the solution to the problem. Let me tell you about my project.

I have a simple play framework application with controllers, services, and a DB layer. Whenever a request comes to the application, a query needs to be fired to DB. My service layer expects a future from DB layers(that's how code is written before me). My controllers return an Action[Result] which expects a future. Either I have to change the whole code base or change the DB library which doesn't use IO and cats. What do you recommend?